# Intranet TFS on VSTS

Tags: .net, tfs, azure-devops, intranet

Can we use intranet TFS for Code along with VSTS for building it using self hosted agents?

i.e. code should be hosted on intranet TFS to avoid sharing of code and Build should be run on local self hosted agent .. but build creation is done on VSTS

Comment: What would the point of using VSTS be? Can you explain what problem you're trying to solve? If you need to secure your source code in VSTS, then hook the account up to Azure Active Directory and use conditional access to limit access to within your intranet.

Comment: Hi Daniel,
Thanks for your comment. Basically I wish not to share my code outside my intra network .. The only point of using VSTS is to make it run build and trigger on checkin using checkin policies .. Since my agent is self hosted .. so it can easily talk to intranet local TFS servers ..

Comment: @Intellex Do you mean that ask VSTS to get the sources from local TFS to build? You have to get sources to build. So, even queue build using VSTS, it also have to get the sources first from local TFS. Why don't you use the intranet local TFS to build the project directly?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT , that's because I want to use the visual features of making build definition .. which I guess can't be done on local , for example my build pipeline uses sonarqube and some powershell scripts .. It is very easy to build these types of complex pipelines in VSTS and then run it using agents ( self hosted ) .. only issue remains is talking to my intranet TFS server .. let me know if i am making sense now?

Comment: @Intellex OK, `only issue remains is talking to my intranet TFS server`, The intranet TFS server machine must be exposed on the internet, the VSTS can get sources from it. If you are using Git on local TFS, then you can Add an external Git service connection point to the local TFS git repository...

Comment: I don't think I have an option to expose intranet tfs on internet ..and we aren't using git .. so can't go for remote Git setup

Comment: @Intellex TFS has the same build system as VSTS. If you're already using an older version of on-prem TFS, you just need to upgrade.

Comment: @DanielMann Can we use TFS to make build definition pipeline just like we can do it in VSTS with all the Tasks such as SonarQube and PowerShell?

Comment: @Intellex Yes. TFS and VSTS are the exact same software, except TFS is installed and maintained on-premises by you, and VSTS is maintained by Microsoft in the cloud.

Comment: @DanielMann thanks a lot for the info, I'll go through it

Comment: @Intellex Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT not yet .. due to some priorities .. will sure update you once I get this done .. thanks for the follow up

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use the files in intranet TFS in the VSTS build.

For Git:

1. Add an External Git service
2. Create a build definition and choose External Git as source

For TFVC, there isn’t the way to get source from TFS in build directly, but you can choose any empty TFVC/git repository in Get sources, then add [Download Artifacts-External TFVC task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.vss-services-externaltfs) to download the source code in TFS.

Make sure the extranet TFS can be accessible from the private agent.

Secondly, the VSTS is newer than TFS, so some features is better than TFS.